# How to fix reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects?

Tags: pandas, for-loop, append

I have tried to loop through some states each year to get the quantile of fPAR for the 1st quantile to the 99th in 5th percentile increments. Attached is the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/117YYIS6abM-IV6qf_ga_wEYwnBF-r1H2/view?usp=share_link) I used, but once I loop through I get the following error once I try to append all data into one pandas data frame:

`Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.read_csv("/DATA.csv")

quantiles = np.array([0.01, 0.05, 0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.25, 0.3 , 0.35, 0.4 , 0.45, 0.5 , 0.55, 0.6 , 0.65, 0.7 , 0.75, 0.8 , 0.85, 0.9 , 0.95, 0.99])

# Loop through every unique state and year
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['NAME', 'year'] + list(quantiles))  # Initialize empty results DataFrame
for state in x['NAME'].unique():
    for year in x['year'].unique():
        state_year_df = x[(x['NAME'] == state) & (x['year'] == year)]  # Subset the data for the current state and year
        if not state_year_df.empty:  # Skip empty subsets
            state_year_quantiles = state_year_df['fPAR'].quantile(q=quantiles)  # Calculate the quantiles
            state_year_results = pd.concat([pd.Series([state, year]), state_year_quantiles.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=0)  # Combine state, year, and quantiles into a single Series
            state_year_results = state_year_results.fillna(0)
            results = results.append(state_year_results, ignore_index=True)  # Append the results for the current state and year to the overall results DataFrame
            print('Quantiles:', state_year_results)
```

How can I append the data without getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to append a series to a dataframe, the series needs to be indexed as the dataframe columns. So your code can add one line.

```
state_year_results.index = ['NAME', 'year'] + list(quantiles)
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.read_csv("/DATA.csv")

quantiles = np.array([0.01, 0.05, 0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.25, 0.3 , 0.35, 0.4 , 0.45, 0.5 , 0.55, 0.6 , 0.65, 0.7 , 0.75, 0.8 , 0.85, 0.9 , 0.95, 0.99])

# Loop through every unique state and year
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['NAME', 'year'] + list(quantiles))  # Initialize empty results DataFrame
for state in x['NAME'].unique():
    for year in x['year'].unique():
        state_year_df = x[(x['NAME'] == state) & (x['year'] == year)]  # Subset the data for the current state and year
        if not state_year_df.empty:  # Skip empty subsets
            state_year_quantiles = state_year_df['fPAR'].quantile(q=quantiles)  # Calculate the quantiles
            state_year_results = pd.concat([pd.Series([state, year]), state_year_quantiles.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=0)  # Combine state, year, and quantiles into a single Series
            state_year_results = state_year_results.fillna(0)
            # => add index to the series
            state_year_results.index = ['NAME', 'year'] + list(quantiles)
            results = results.append(state_year_results, ignore_index=True)  # Append the results for the current state and year to the overall results DataFrame
            print('Quantiles:', state_year_results)
```

Another method is to use groupby and unstack.

```
results = x.groupby(['NAME', 'year'])['fPAR'].quantile(q=quantiles).unstack(2).reset_index().sort_values(['NAME', 'year']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result is same as the first one.